# For loop matrix with one variable m

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have problem with for loop matrix with one variable m.
How to solve this matrix with for loop?

[1 1/2 ... 1/m+1, 1/2 1/3 ... 1/m+2, ... ... ..., 1/m+1 1/m+2 ... 1/2m+1]

Comment: I have no clue what the pattern is supposed to be here.

Comment: @beaker From what I understand, it is `1/1, 1/2 , 1/3 , 1/4, .... 1/m, 1/(m+1)` The number in the denominator is increasing. Then next it starts from `1/2` and ends at `1/(m+2)`  and so on

Comment: As Sardar Usama said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB r2016b or Octave You can write:

```
1./reshape((1:m+1).'+(0:m),1,[])
```

In previous versions you can do:

```
1./reshape(bsxfun(@plus, (1:m+1).', 0:m), 1, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sardar Usama for providing me a site to verify my code without running Matlab on my own computer.

Sample code:

```
m1 = repelem(1:m+1,m+1);
m2 = repmat(0:m,1,m+1);
m3 = m1+m2;
mmatrix = 1./m3;
msum = sum(mmatrix);
mmean = mean(mmatrix);
% mwhatever = whatever(mmatrix)
```

If you do not have `repelem` in your Matlab version, replace the line with `repelem` with the following

```
m1 = repmat(1:m+1,m+1,1);
m1 = reshape(m1,1,[]);
```

Sample output for `m=5`

```
m3 =

 Columns 1 through 16:

    1    2    3    4    5    6    2    3    4    5    6    7    3    4    5    6

 Columns 17 through 32:

    7    8    4    5    6    7    8    9    5    6    7    8    9   10    6    7

 Columns 33 through 36:

    8    9   10   11

mmatrix =

 Columns 1 through 7:

   1.000000   0.500000   0.333333   0.250000   0.200000   0.166667   0.500000

 Columns 8 through 14:

   0.333333   0.250000   0.200000   0.166667   0.142857   0.333333   0.250000

 Columns 15 through 21:

   0.200000   0.166667   0.142857   0.125000   0.250000   0.200000   0.166667

 Columns 22 through 28:

   0.142857   0.125000   0.111111   0.200000   0.166667   0.142857   0.125000

 Columns 29 through 35:

   0.111111   0.100000   0.166667   0.142857   0.125000   0.111111   0.100000

 Column 36:

   0.090909

mmean =  0.21774
```

Comment: It doesn't work well. 

In output mmatrix is 1x100 double

Comment: @SardarUsama Thanks

Comment: @SzymonPłotka In question you wrote a vector with square bracket so I assumed you expect a vector output. What exactly do you want?

Comment: If I declare (eg. m = 6), I want to sum matrix, median, mean, var etc.

Comment: @SzymonPłotka Edited answer.